# HDMI output going blank for few seconds every so often: how to troubleshoot without losing sanity?

Tags: linux, display, hdmi, external-display

I've wired up an external display to my laptop, and sometimes the output just disappears for 2-3 seconds before reappearing. I'm using the external display as the primary display (not showing anything on my laptop's own display).

I'm wondering what the cause of this could be. The display works with other HDMI sources, and my laptop has previously worked with other displays. The blanking doesn't seem to be correlated with me moving (and hence the wire moving).

Are there any sane ways to troubleshoot this? For instance,

1. How could I check that my laptop is consistently giving the monitor the output it wants? (i.e. it's not a software issue)
2. How could I monitor the wired connection? (e.g. something similar to `ping` utility where I could record a momentary disconnection, if it's due to the wire)

Preferably tools find information on the above two would work on either linux or windows.

Answer (score 0):

Best to test the actual hardware first, in my opinion.

> my laptop has previously worked with other displays

Well, does it still work with other displays now? If not, it might be a hardware issue (graphics card probably), but it could be a software issue ... were new drivers installed with windows update for example?

Also, does your display work fine on another computer? If it does, then you know for sure that the problem lies within your computer (be it hardware or software). If it doesn't, you've found the issue.

If both options work (your display on another PC, and another display on your PC), it might be a driver issue for that particular display on your computer. Try updating the drivers for both GPU and display.

Comment: Don't actually have other displays to test on now. I understand what you're saying -- single out the problem by looking at it as a black box and seeing what works and what doesn't, but I actually want to know if there are tools that let me peer inside the black box so I can see what's going on.

Comment: I understand - I don't know of any such tools. Google is your friend, unless someone else chimes in with some software. I'd still try to update the drivers if you can't test your hardware.